# Problema con media queries

Tags: css, asp.net, mediaqueries

Aclaro antes que soy nuevo en esto,
Tengo un proyecto de ASP.NET al cual le agregue mi hoja de estilos, en esa hoja trato de incluir un media querie pero parece que no funciona.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Nebulosa</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body class="fondo-gris">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top menu_gral " role="navigation" style="box-shadow:10px 5px 15px; ">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Nebulosa", "Principal", "Menu", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">

                    <li class="dropdown icono">

                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th glypStyle" ></i>Flujo Caja<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropDownEstilo">
                            <li><a>@Html.ActionLink("Flujo de Caja Diario", "Index", "FlujosCaja")</a></li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Borrar Flujo de Caja", "IndexBorrar", "FlujosCaja")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown icono">

                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench glypStyle" ></i>Mantenimiento<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropDownEstilo">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Colaborador", "Index", "Colaboradores")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Movimiento", "Index", "Movimientos")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Proveedor", "Index", "Proveedores")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Usuario", "Index", "Usuarios")</li>
                            @*<li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Producto<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tipos de Producto", "Index", "TiposProducto")</li>
                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Categorias de Tipo de Producto", "Index", "CategoriasTipoProducto")</li>
                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Productos", "Index", "Productos")</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>*@
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown icono">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt glypStyle" ></i>Reportes<b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropDownEstilo">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Flujo de Caja", "Index", "ReporteFlujosCaja")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Utilidad por Rango de Fecha", "Index", "ReporteUtilidadRangoFecha")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid body-content" style="padding: 45px 25px 0px 25px" ;>
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p align="right">&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Nebulosa</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script src="~/Scripts/Programacion/Menu.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Y este es el css

```
    .table-style {
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    background-color: white;
}
.tableTitle thead{
        color:black;
        font-weight:700;
        text-decoration:underline;
}
.graficoVentas {
        margin-top: 10px
}
.fondo-gris {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    padding: 50px 25px 0px 25px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) and (max-height: 768px) {
    .fondo-gris {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
.icono {
    /*display: flex !important;*/
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
}
.icono a{
    padding-left:8px !important;
}
.dropDownEstilo {
    background-color:#333;
    border-radius:10px !important;
}
.dropDownEstilo a {
    color:white !important;
}
.menu_gral li a:hover,
menu_gral li a:focus {
    background: #444;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50px !important;
}
.glypStyle {
    color: white;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Seria mucho mejor que pusieras el codigo asi podriamos ayudarte

Comment: por cierto aparte del comentario que te hice mas abajo, debo aclararte que el código va como texto y no como imagen, una vez pegado seleccionalo y dale clic al ícono `{}`

Comment: listo, gracias por informarme!

Comment: Exactamente que es lo que quieres que haga? A que te refieres con que no funciona? Gracias :)

Comment: Sí que funciona, cuando el navegador es menor de 900px de ancho y 768px de alto cambia el color del fondo. No veo el problema

Comment: Exacto el codigo esta bien, pero a la hora de ejecutarlo chrome no reconoce el media querie... cuando voy a las herramientas entro en la carpeta styles y aparece toda la clase excepto el media....

Comment: He probado en chrome tu código y funciona correctamente.